# fpcmake and Makefile.fpc, where can I get some training?

Tags: makefile, freepascal, fpc

I've never used any of these, but they are listed on the main Free Pascal site and I would really like to get my hands on:

- Beginners guide, to get me started
- Advanced guide, to help me grow

All this in case it's still used/standard.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO makefile.fpc is mostly FPC internal. I wouldn't use it for own projects.

The idea is that Makefile.fpc is combined with a template fpcmake.ini by running "fpcmake -Tall -w" to generate a GNU Makefile. The fpcmake.ini template is built in into the fpcmake binary.

Makefile.fpc is a file that has parameters for customizing the (fpcmake.ini) template, but can also add additional targets (in makefile format).

To my knowledge there is a paragraph about fpcmake somewhere in the documentation, nad the rest is usually learned by example, simple usage in packages/ and the more complicated examples are the toplevel makefile.fpc and the ones in compiler and rtl/

Comment: Thanks Marco. So what would one use as a lightweight or even heavy duty was of repeating compiles?

Comment: Since FPC typically compilesi in one command, I type it directly, or for larger cmdlines I use shell/batchfiles, or simply use Lazarus IDE.